# Supply arguments to AppEngineLauncher via google plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I want to pass command-line arguments like `--address` to the development server from my Eclipse environment.  When I try to add them to the arguments in my run configurations, they're passed to GWT dev mode instead of the appengine server.  What can I do to pass things down to the appengine server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing a custom launcher class.  Parameters on the command line were being passed to the GWT code server but not the appengine web server, so simple command line arguments wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

DevMode can take the arguments `-bindAddress someaddress.com`, and it will pass these on to the servlet container it's using.

(That doesn't solve your problem in general, but if all you need is to pass on the address, this should do the trick.)